# What to give in Project ID?

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging

[image: Enter "ProjectID": "Register ProjectID"]

It is asking to enter "ProjectID" in image: "Register ProjectID" , do we need to give projectID which is already geenrated by google in the URL something like: project:999999999 - 10 digits one ??

Comment: What is this? Can you clarify what you are trying to do? What service are you using?

Comment: I have registered with Google Cloud Messaging, for the android push notifications application using phonegap(with out using third party to push notifications). After all I configured I could not get what to fill in this field. I am getting an INVALID REGISTRATION as the server response and I am worried may be this one I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"DNS-compatible" typically means of the form "com.mycompany.myproject". Not numeric. See the format specifier in the bottom: "Must start with a letter".